# Copy content of a same file to a working copy in TortoiseSVN

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

**Question**: If no one else has made any changes to a file, say File1 in working directory of a project and I've an exact copy of the same file, say File2 on another folder outside the working folder. If I just copy/paste the content of the File2 to File1, will there be any issues on doing so?

**Note**: The file is about two pages long and is a programming file (like Python, C#, Java etc.). I'm using latest version of TortoiseSVN on Windows 10.

**UPDATE**:

I forgot to mention that I have made several changes to File2 and instead of making same changes one by one to File1 I just would like to copy/paste the content of File2 to File1 and then commit the changes to repository.

Comment: Did you give it a try? Just copy the file and see if TortoiseSVN --> Check for Modifications shows some modifications

Comment: @royalTS I have just added an **UPDATE** to my post to clarify my question a bit more.

Comment: But still the same question from my side, did you give it a try? Because I remember that it is possible. Otherwise you could use a tool like beyond compare to quickly transfer your changes